# Simplest solution to: "onClick" event changes Icon's "color" (Platform = Carrd.co)

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, icons

[nav menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9lQ4.png)
I have a fixed header **nav menu** of *Icons* for a video gallery. Currently, the icons change color on hover.

I want add an "onclick" event to **change the Icon color** as to indicate one's nav menu position in video gallery.

The platform is **Carrd.co**. There isn't direct access to the code, yet **one can insert code snippets**. Below are two instructions about the code listed.

[1) To assign an event to an icon, use the icon's "onclick" setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Rmn.png)

[2) Code input field - example of: console.log('clicked!');](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaznL.png)

There is a note: "Code to run when a user clicks this icon."

So I'm trying to find the simplest solution to paste into the "**On Click**" *entry field* (visual: code input field image above).

Ive tried pasting "icon color change code solutions" from various sources out there. They all made the site not appear. My guess is I'm pasting too much or too little into the single field.